# how to fix EXE4J_JAVA_HOME, No JVM could be found on your system error?

Tags: java, exe4j

I installed java 64bit 1.7 and exe4j 64bit version. I tried to generate an exe from exe4j, but while running the program I'm having this error.

This is how I set up path variable. And this is right jre path. What did I miss here?  please let me know.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried this http://wincrunch.com/exe4j-java-home-no-jvm-could-be-found-on-your-system/ ?

Comment: @yasel yes. both answers are not working for me :(

Comment: restart your IDE in order to read the newly introduced environment variable

Comment: its not IDE its Exe4j

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has to be done during your exe4j configuration.
In the fourth step of Exe4j wizard which is **Executable Info** select> **Advanced options** select **32-bit or 64-bit**. This worked well for me.
or else install both JDK tool-kits x64 and x32 in your machine.

Comment: i met with the same problem and this worked fine for me.

Answer (score 15):

In my case (OWASP Zap scanner) I had to install the latest OpenJDK from https://adoptium.net

Comment: the ZAP installer message is missleading, ask myself what they do as product, if even the install does not work as it should

Comment: Finally! I was looking for a solution after installing 3 different versions of the JRE. The message is misleading indeed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the 32 bit version of Java 6. This works for version Install4J 4.0.5. Should fire right up, or allow you to re-run the installer.

Any newer version or the 64-bit version of 6 will fail, complaining that the java.exe is damaged.

Answer (score 1):

There are few steps to overcome this problem:

1. Uninstall Java related softwares
2. Uninstall NodeJS if installed
3. Download java 8 update161
4. Install it

**The problem solved:** The problem raised to me at the uninstallation on openfire server.

Answer (score 0):

BH's answer of installing Java 6u45 was very close... still got the popup on reboot...BUT after uninstalling Java 6u45, rebooted, no warning! Thank you BH!
Then installed the latest version, 8u151-i586, rebooted no warning.

I added lines in PATH as above, didn't do anything.

My system: Windows 7, 64 bit. Warning was for No JVM, 32 bit Java not found.
Yes, I could have installed the 64 bit version, but 32bit is more compatible with all programs.

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue with the Java JDK/JRE package itself, try downloading & installing/configuring latest version of JDK, followed by system restart. It worked for me and it may work for you too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. With the difference that I wanted to use the 32-bit version. The only way I could solve the problem was to install the 32-bit version of Windows XP on a virtual machine!!

Answer (score -1):

Leave you stuff there and Try the following as well:

Start > Right-click on My computer > Properties > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables > look for variable name called "Path" in the lower box

set path value value as: (you can just add it to the starting of line, don't forgot semi column in between )

```
c:\Program Files\java\jre7\bin
```

Comment: click start and in the command window, type, cmd, then type java -d64. what did you see ?

Comment: loys of details. what u wana know?

Comment: that means you are pointing to the right java 64 bit version. your exe4j is also installed in program files not Program files(X86)?

Comment: Problem is I can't find it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85226/discussion-between-jegg-and-pippi-longstocking).

Comment: hey I found it. it is 64 bit and I'm using java 1.7. I don't know what is the wrong

Answer (score -2):

It worked for me, but the exe4j can leave a signature when you double click the .exe application

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? "It worked for me" is not sufficient, and the second half of your answer does not seem to give a clear solution to the OP's problem.